# FIPS with Oracle using Entity Framework - ORA- 01017

Tags: windows, wcf, oracle11g, entity-framework-6, fips

I am using Entity Framework 6 for Oracle to fetch some information in WCF Service, the service works well on my local machine but when i deploy my code to production environment which is on WIN 2012 which has FIPS policy enforcement then my WCF service give me error of **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x000003F9): ORA-01017: invalid username/password**, even i have set enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false" under runtime tag in my web.config, but it seems this tag doesnt work if the server enforces to use FIPS.

However when i reset the registry value for FIPS from "1" to "0" from (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>System>CurrentControlSet>Lsa>FIPSAlgorithmPolicy) the ORA-01017 exception doesnt come and it returns data.

So would like to know how to disable FIPS at application level, when domain/GPO enforces it. As this has been really a challenge for me for last 2 days.

Thanks.

Comment: well i learned to know that, EF 6 with Managed ODP.NET with 12c Db client and 11g DB under FIPS 140 compliant server has a reported bug in oracle, the workaround is to use unmanaged odp.net if Db upgrade is not possible.